# I am having video-course about creating Slack chat and now i have some problems

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to output messages from database(firebase).
In console everything okay, but when it doesn't show in the component.
Looks like i have some problems with Message component, but idk...

https://github.com/Dronrom/app here is the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtP7e.png)

It's supposed to be like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you forgot to return Node Elements from your displayMessages method.

This may help you:

```
 displayMessages = messages => {
    // Check if message list is not empty
    if(messages.length > 0) {
        // Create new constant and collect it with messages
        const messagesList = messages.map(message => (
            <Message 
                key={message.timestamp}
                message={message}
                user={this.state.user}
            />
        ))

        // Return React Nodes collection from method
        return messagesList;
    }
    // Return null when message list is empty
    return null;
}
```

Btw you got to many unnecessary rerenders when getting data from firebase

Comment: Thank you very much)))even if i write return before it works well=)